# Create php variables from post data

Tags: php

I have ajax data being passed to my php email processing file - contact.php - using this simple post function:

```
$.post('contact.php', post_data, function(response) {
        var rout = response.text;
        // do something w/ response
```

`post_data` is a simple object. Data is formatted in key/value pairs like this: `{Name: 'me', Email: 'me@site.com'}`

The key names will not be known ahead of time, so I need to find a way to loop through post_data & create variables in php, preferably w/ the same name, i.e. `$name` for Name, `$email` for Email, etc.

I also need a way to add these variables & their values to the `$message_body` like this:

```
<br />Name: me <br />
Email: me@site.com
```

Comment: They will all be in the `$_POST` array, no need to loop through and create. For example `$_POST['Email']` will contain me@site.com

Comment: As I said, I will not know the names of the keys, so have to find a way to create variables to contain the values

Comment: Possible [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: No - they are already named in their identifier.

Comment: Do you know what is `$_POST`?

Comment: How will you not know the key/pairs ahead of time?

Comment: These key/pairs will be set up by other parties - it's a form plugin, so I have no way of knowing what they will choose to use in their forms.

Comment: If you don't know chosen names - how will you know what variables do you have?

Comment: But it will always generate a `$_POST` array for which there is no need of conversion. Converting would not help you anyhow, because you would not know the names of the new variables either.

Comment: You can use `extract($_POST, EXTR_SKIP);` EXTR_SKIP will prevent overwriting the existing variables.

Comment: I'm really curious what could be advantageous about putting the values in separate variables rather than $_POST keys.

Comment: ***Warning Do not use `extract()` on untrusted data***, like user input (i.e. `$_GET`, `$_FILES`, etc.). If you do, for example if you want to temporarily run old code that relied on register_globals, make sure you use one of the non-overwriting flags values such as EXTR_SKIP and be aware that you should extract in the same order that's defined in variables_order within the php.ini.

Comment: @parti what problem are you trying to solve? Can you tell us more?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Re: your warning: could a standard filter_var() w/ Filter_Sanitize_string be used?  Re: problem:  It's a email form plugin, so I can't predict the variables (otherwise it would be easy), so looking for a solution :)

Comment: Have you tried using regex and algorithms to identify the value and place in the right variable? If variables are created dynamically, you would need to maintain a whitelist.

Comment: If it is an email form plugin it will always have the same input fields, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously your solution is iterating over `$_POST` array with key-value, where `key` will be the **name** of input on your form, and `value` - the **value** of this input.

```
$message_body = '';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $message_body .= $key . ': ' . $value . '<br />';
}
```

**Update:** you can do whatever filtering and sanitizing:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    // or check with `in_array()`
    if ($key != 'excluded_key_1') {
        $message_body .= sanitizeValue($key) . ': ' . sanitizeValue($value) . '<br />';
    }
}
```

where `sanitizeValue` is your function which sanitizes your data, for example.

Comment: @u_mulder, so all key/values will exist.  To be safe can I add a sanitize statement before adding the key to $message_body?

Comment: @u_mulder  There are a couple of key/flags that I don't want placed in the $message_body  These special keys will be known, Ex. Filecheck  So how would I prevent Filecheck from being written out?